# Python reduce() Function for 0

Tags: python

i have `vals = [1.0, 0.0, 3.4, 0.0]` and I want to avoid multiplying by zero

if i use `reduce(operator.mul, iterable)` - i get 0.0.

Also for `reduce(lambda x, y : x * y, val)` too

How can I add the minimum conditions for variables so that only get greater than zero. But if the array was completely out of zero elements, then it returned 0. Zero element from an array can not be deleted

So for `vals = [1.0, 0.0, 3.4, 0.0]` - return 3.4

for `vals = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` - return 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove `0`s from the list. If the list becomes empty, return `0`, the product otherwise:

```
>>> no_zeroes = [value for value in values if value > 0]
>>> no_zeroes
[1.0, 3.4]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y : y*x, no_zeroes) if no_zeroes else 0
3.4
```

Note that from a mathematical point of view, the product of an empy list should probably be `1`. In that case, you could write :

```
reduce(lambda x, y : y*x, no_zeroes, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use numpy arrays you can filter out the zero values:

```
import numpy as np
vals = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
no_zeros = vals[vals>0]
if no_zeros:
    print( np.prod(no_zeros))
else:
    print(0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
from functools import reduce

vals = [1.0, 0.0, 3.4, 0.0]
reduce(lambda x,y: y if x == 0 else (x if y == 0 else x*y), vals, 0)
# 3.4

vals = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
reduce(lambda x,y: y if x == 0 else (x if y == 0 else x*y), vals, 0)
# 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out 0.0 values with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

```
from functools import reduce

vals_without_zero = filter(lambda x: x, vals)
reduce(lambda x, y : x * y, vals_without_zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining `functools.reduce` (with *initiator* value `1`) and `filter` functions:

```
vals = [1.0, 0.0, 3.4, 0.0]
result = functools.reduce(operator.mul, list(filter(lambda x: x>0, vals)) or [0], 1)
print(result)  #  3.4
```

---

```
vals = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
result = functools.reduce(operator.mul, list(filter(lambda x: x>0, vals)) or [0], 1)
print(result)  # 0
```